# How do i get Vector<type> Arraylist<type> as return of call()?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, callable

how do I get the following Java code to work:

```
public class Worker implements Callable<myObject>{

   @Override
   public ArrayList<myObject> call() throws Exception {
      ArrayList<myObject> lst_MyObjects= new ArrayList<myObject>();     
      return lst_MyObjects;
   }
}
```

Error: The return type is incompatible with Callable.call()

I just want to return a container of a specific type (`Vector<>` / `ArrayList<>` etc.)

Comment: java.util.concurrent.Callable ?

Comment: There's a tutorial for the use of Callable here: https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use this:

```
public class Worker implements Callable<List<myObject>>{
```

By using `List`, you can return either an `ArrayList` or a `Vector`, though its advisable to use `ArrayList` instead of a `Vector`.

Comment: oh.. what a dumb mistake..
thanks a lot for the fast response

Answer (score 2):

It must be `Callable<List<myObject>>` because `ArrayList<myObject>`is the return type, not myObject.

Comment: If you use a `Callable<ArrayList<myObject>>`, then a `Vector` can't be returned. Better to use `Callable<List<myObject>>`

Comment: Good point, haven't got this contstraint into account posting this.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the return type of the method `call()`

from `ArrayList<myObject>` to `Object`